# Woocommerce: How to change position of error message in cart page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display woocommerce cart error messages and notices in top of header. 
I have put `wc_print_notices();`  in top of header but it still did not work for me.

For example if I apply any coupon, it shows success or error message that displays within cart instead of header.

Is there any way to change position of the error messages that are produced by ajax ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create template of cart page in your theme folder as per the woocommerce rule and edit your cart.php file according to your requirement.